# Why are some apps transparent when using specific themes?

Tags: themes, gtk3, 15.10

I've noticed that some apps becomes transparent when using a couple of themes. I've noticed this with Geary and Corebird with either the Numix or the Ultra Flat theme.

Anybody knows a way to fix this? I really love those themes, but the way some apps look makes me almost want to go back to default...

[image]

**Using 15.10 now**

Output of apt-cache policy corebird:

```
corebird:
  Installed: 1.1~really1.0.1-2
  Candidate: 1.1~really1.0.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.1~really1.0.1-2 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of grep Exec= /usr/share/applications/org.baedert.corebird.desktop:

```
Exec=env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 corebird
```

After updating to 15.10:
[image: Fixed after upgrading to 15.10]

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm using version 15.04.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-get policy corebird`

Comment: and add the output of `grep Exec=  /usr/share/applications/org.baedert.corebird.desktop`

Comment: Has been added :)

Comment: and `apt-get policy corebird` please

Comment: I did add the output of that, but it returned "Invalid operation policy". However, after upgrading to 15.10 it seems like everything is alright now... Strange. Any reason to this?

Comment: Ups, sorry `apt-cache policy corebird`

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/corebird?field.series_filter=vivid):

> As a workaround to fix the background transparency issue (#169), I've
>   edited the .desktop file so that the Corebird window will use the old
>   fat scroll bars instead of the Overlay scroll bars.

Therefore use another PPA or upgrade the installed version of Corebird

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Your `/usr/share/applications/org.baedert.corebird.desktop` should now have a row like this

```
Exec=env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 corebird
```

---

And as you said, you have upgraded your system and now it works in 15.10, I have the perfect answer for you:

*Upgrade your system to 15.10* **;)**

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Well, I can't really check whether or not this would fix anything since the problem more or less fixed itself when upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10, it seems. Thanks for the help though. :) I shouldn't mark the answer as accepted when I haven't been able to test, right?

Comment: @DennisSkovHermannsen: Well, what you have done is slightly unfair on those who have answered your question. But I would suggest that you do at some point test this in a VM or something just to help others in the future.

Comment: The answer that was given was only a fix for Corebird, if I'm not mistaken. The transparent window wasn't only with Corebird, but a couple of other apps, including Geary. I've unfortunately forgot the rest of the apps.

The upgrade to 15.10 had nothing to do with trying to solve this issue.

Comment: @DennisSkovHermannsen: Sorry to say but this kind of behaviour will get you shunned from further help from high-ranking users...  (highly upvoted answer; no acceptance)  **;-)**

Comment: So, let me get this straight. I ask a question, somehow fix my issue by accident, I tell people that the issue was fixed, a person comes and tells me about a work-around for only a small part of my problem (this provided answer only fixes the issue in Corebird - not any other apps), I upvote his answer to show that I appreciate his help, and I get downvoted for essentially not having a problem anymore? That's it? I read that I should only accept an answer if it solved the issue for me, **which it didnt**. I do appreciate the help, like I said, but I really don't see were I made a mistake.

Comment: I have added the perfect solution for you in my answer: Upgrade your system to 15.10 ;)